# Division question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does one get from the first to the second (math) line in this:

> Let us now write $1/(z-x)$ in the following way: 
>   $$
> \dfrac1{z-x}=\dfrac1{z-a-(x-a)}=\dfrac1{z-a}\left(\frac1{1-\dfrac{x-a}{z-a}}\right),
> $$
>   or, carrying out the division up to the remainder of degree $n+1$ is $x-a$,
>   $$\begin{align*}
> \dfrac1{z-x}=\dfrac1{z-a}&+\dfrac{x-a}{(x-a)^2}+\dfrac{(x-a)^2}{(x-a)^3}+\cdots \\ &+\dfrac{(x-a)^n}{(x-a)^{n+1}}+\dfrac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(z-x)(z-a)^{n+1}}.
> \end{align*}$$

Looks like you're expanding a geometric series, with finite number of terms, sadly thinking that way I don't see where the $\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(z-x)(z-a)^{n+1}}$ term comes from. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Write

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{x-a}{z-a}} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-a)^k}{(z-a)^k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{(x-a)^k}{(z-a)^k}.$$

Pull out a factor of $\left(\frac{x-a}{z-a}\right)^{n+1}$ from the second sum to see it is

$$\frac{\left(\frac{x-a}{z-a}\right)^{n+1}}{1 - \frac{x-a}{z-a}} = \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{\bigl((z-a) - (x-a)\bigr)(z-a)^n} = \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(z-x)(z-a)^n}.$$

Multiply with $\frac{1}{z-a}$ to obtain

$$\frac{1}{z-x} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(x-a)^k}{(z-a)^{k+1}} + \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(z-x)(z-a)^{n+1}}.$$